# How can I place a date in dd/mm/yyyy format into an Excel cell with VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, format, date

I want to fill a cell in a worksheet with the date as string and I want it to be in the dd/mm/yyyy format. I use the following code but it keeps showing as mm/dd/yyyy. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong since I already looked up the answer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim date1 As String
    date1 = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Range("B1") = date1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Format before placing a value in the cell:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1")
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Value = Date
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Good Day,

Seems like the underlying format to the cell overrides the formatting in your VBA. I just went and added a custom format before running the code. Which I had a better suggestion. You probably don't need the image, but..

[image]